# model does not get updated inside of a foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not sure what is happening.

`docsRelacionadosModel` is a model that has this structure:

`docsRelacionadosModel.idDocTipo` that is a *integer*

and has those elementes: `[0]:76 , [1]:76, [2]:74`

In this code:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var m in docsRelacionadosModel)
{
    resultadoDialogModel dialogTemp = new resultadoDialogModel();
    if (i == 0) //FIRST TIME
    {
        idTipoSendoVerificado = m.idDocTipo; //HERE GETS '46'

    }
    else
    {
        // Here, first time is equal ([0]46 == [1]46)
        if (m.idDocTipo == idTipoSendoVerificado)
        {   
            //if there where no more element, but do not get here
            if (i == (docsRelacionadosModel.Count() - 1))
            {
                dialogTemp.tipo = m.idDocTipo;
                dialog.Add(dialogTemp);
            } 
        } 
        else //For the third and also the last time [1]46 != [2]44
        {
            dialogTemp.tipo = idTipoSendoVerificado; //Should be 46
            dialog.Add(dialogTemp); //Save tempModel in model
            idTipoSendoVerificado = m.idDocTipo; //Update id been verified

            if (i == (docsRelacionadosModel.Count() - 1)) // And it is the last index
            {
               dialogTemp.tipo = idTipoSendoVerificado; //Here should be 44
               dialog.Add(dialogTemp); //Save tempModel in model
            }
        }  
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now when I print the value of `dialog.tipo` I should get `[0]:46 / [1]:44`
But I am getting `[0]:44 / [1]:44`

I am not sure if this is because the value is passed as reference so when I change `idTipoSendoVerificado` for the third iteraction it changes the alread saved value in the model.

If it is confusing, please, tell me and I´ll try to fix for a better understanding.

Comment: Have you got (i != 0)?

Comment: This is really confusing. Try to execute the code in a separate project and remove the lines you don't need to show the problem. You've put the `i++` in a spot that won't be reached now, and we've got no idea what the other code could be doing with side effects. I'm also not sure where the 46 comes from, since you've got 3 instances of some class (specify that too, please), with `idDocTipo` values of 76, 76, and 74.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `var dialogTemp2 = new resultadoDialogModel();`, set `dialogTemp2.tipo = idTipoSendoVerificado;` then add that new element in `dialog`:

```
if (i == (docsRelacionadosModel.Count() - 1)) // And it is the last index
{
    var dialogTemp2 = new resultadoDialogModel();
    dialogTemp2.tipo = idTipoSendoVerificado; //Here should be 44
    dialog.Add(dialogTemp2); //Save tempModel in model
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your i++ is inside the outer 'else', you probably want it 1 line lower, inside just the foreach.

You now have all items treated as 'first time'. The relevant lines:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var m in docsRelacionadosModel)
{     
    if (i == 0) //FIRST TIME
    {
       ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
        i++;
    }
}
```

`i` will always be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `dialogTemp` this is a reference of an object, when you made `dialog.Add(dialogTemp);` (I'm guessing because I don't know the type or dialog) you just reference the object and you are not making a new object, you change the id `dialogTemp.tipo = idTipoSendoVerificado;` and add the object again `dialog.Add(dialogTemp);` now you have the same object referenced in [0] and in [1], is the same object, because is not a value pass is a reference pass, so, if you change the object you change the object in all his references.

You can make a new instance of the object to solve this, you need to make a new dialogTemp()...